# Which is better for a beginner Yokto project or OpenEmbedded , building one's own embedded distro?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, openembedded

After watching some videos/conferences, reading documentations ... I am still unable to decide which is better : OpenEmbedded or Yocto for building one's own real time distro ( better said linux kernel ).

The project i am working on is time limited ( i can tolerate atmost one month to make the distro work on the target , some peripherals will be added later ) . 
So i do not want to be in time frustration later , i asked you to have an estimated trend based on your experience and what may add me more values in my professional experience .

My target is planned to be the NI MyRIO Board , the system main objective is managing a sensors net .

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I think you should ask this question [here](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/ni-linux-real-time?view=discussions).

Comment: Use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/about.html). What you *"learned"* about it is wrong. BTW if you're not going to "distribute" it, then you are not building a *"distro"* but a kernel and rootfs for your own specific use.  Otherwise *"one's own distro"* is an oxymoron.

Comment: Hi @sawdust , yes you are right and there have i edited it .

Answer (score 9):

Let the debate begin ;).  I have used and written about all three: OpenEmbedded, Yocto, and Buildroot.  Here's my personal perspective.  OpenEmbedded (OE) can be considered the "upstream" for Yocto Project.  Yocto Project builds on OE and adds preconfigured BSPs and distro defaults which makes it easier to build for those BSPs that are supported by a given Yocto release.  Yocto Project and OE project cooperate very closely.  Buildroot is also a good build system, but the market has spoken.  Every major semiconductor manufacturer and embedded Linux OS vendor has jumped on the Yocto Project bandwagon.  Buildroot project has not enjoyed that popularity.  Buildroot is good technology, and has some top-notch engineers contributing to it, but OE and Yocto has many more active developers and contributors.  That's the way I see it.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: thanks @challinan , yes you are right , i learned so too , the Yokto project release is synchronous with those of OpenEmbedded and bitbake tool , but cannot understand the layers notion , should i as beginner master it or there is some workaround?

Comment: There is a small learning curve to get the layer and basic configuration straight. But you can easily start with the Yocto base image and build your own stuff on top of it. I have seen projects that did it this way and I did the same. Creating my own layer for my own stuff though, so its worth to have a basic understanding and your own layer to integrate easily with Yocto updates etc.  All information are based on personally opinion. They might not be "best practice"